# Get identity of last inserted row in pervasive SQL

Tags: odbc, pervasive-sql

I'm trying to retrieve the identity of last inserted row and I want to use scope_identity. The system is developing in ASP.NET and pervasive SQL using ODBC. I thought my google skills were good but I can't find anything about this, is it even possible?

Grateful for any answer or someone pointing in any direction helping me solve this.

Comment: @Dennis... I get "error in expression" so i guess not... :S

Comment: @Dennis, nope, it says ASP.NET in the text of the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the field has an `Identity` field, you can issue a `SELECT @@identity` to get the last identity value inserted.

Comment: I have an identity field but still don't return anything... and is @@identity scope specific, can't find any information about that, what i want is something similar to MSSql SCOPE_IDENTITY

Comment: Pervasive SQL does not support the SCOPE_IDENTITY.  From the documentation, @@identity returns the value of the most recently inserted Identity column.  If the table does not have an identity column, @@identity will return null.  If you have two inserts, the @@identity returns the last value inserted.